# Nested Fragments Communication

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

I'm currently having trouble with nesting fragments , I've created a `SlidingTabLayout` with two tabs , each tab with it's corresponding Fragment , In one tab I've added 5 child fragments to the parent fragment returned by the `FragmentPagerAdapter`, but I'm having trouble with the communication between the parent fragment and it's fragment children ,

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            FragmentTransaction childManager=getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            childManager.add(R.id.linear08,new YearFragment08(),"year08");
            childManager.commit();
            YearFragment08 year08=(YearFragment08)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("year08");
            year08.setinfo("This is fantastic");


}
```

`

```
public class YearFragment08 extends Fragment {
TextView yearInfo;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.year_frag08,container,false);
    yearInfo=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_yearInfo_08);
    return v;
}
 public void setinfo(String data){
    yearInfo.setText(data);
}
```

And THIS is the result .

```
02-09 21:45:48.078    2177-2177/com.compassasu.compass E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.compassasu.compass, PID: 2177
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.compassasu.compass.Fragments.YearFragment08.setinfo(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.compassasu.compass.Fragments.HistoryFragment.onActivityCreated(HistoryFragment.java:33)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1970)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1051)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:545)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

All I want to know is how does a child fragment receive data from the parent fragment .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to find the fragment by its tag before it has actually been added. Note the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit()) for `FragmentTransaction.commit()`:

> Schedules a commit of this transaction. The commit does not happen
>   immediately; it will be scheduled as work on the main thread to be
>   done the next time that thread is ready.

As you can see the fragment is not added immediately so that is why `null` is returned when you try to get the `Fragment`.

To fix this you can use `FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()` after committing the transaction to add the fragment immediately:

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.linear08,new YearFragment08(),"year08")
        .commit();

getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
YearFragment08 year08=(YearFragment08)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("year08");
year08.setinfo("This is fantastic");
```

---

Also note that a better way to do this would be to create the `YearFragment08` fragment first and use `Fragment` arguments to pass the info you want to show in the `Fragment`. Then you would not need to use the above workaround since you will not need to call `yearInfo.setText("Hi")` when the `Fragment` is first created. You can find an example of creating a `Fragment` with arguments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9245510/1435985).

**Update**

As noted in the lengthy comments although the first approach allows `getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("year08")` to return the fragment it is still not a good idea to call any methods on the `Fragment` that access its views until `onViewStateRestored(...)` or after has been called.

This is because when using the `FragmentManager` to add the parent fragment the child fragment's `onCreateView` method will not be called immediately after calling `executePendingTransactions()` so the child fragment's referenced views are null. If the parent `Fragment` is used directly in the layout this is not a problem as `onCreateView` of the child fragment is called as part of `executePendingTransactions()` and its views will not be null.

The best thing to do in this case would be to use the other approach as mentioned that uses `Fragment` arguments if you need to set initial values for views within fragments.

Comment: 02-09 22:30:07.148    7381-7381/com.compassasu.compass E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.compassasu.compass, PID: 7381
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at com.compassasu.compass.Fragments.YearFragment08.setinfo(YearFragment08.java:27)

Still didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Actually it did work as you now made it into the `setText` method of your `Fragment`. New issues is the `yearInfo` text view is `null` in your `setInfo` method. Are you sure it is assigned in the `onCreateView` method of `YearFragment08`? Double check the `year_frag08.xml` file for a `TextView` with `id=txt_yearInfo_08`.

Comment: <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
android:id="@+id/txt_yearInfo_08"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? Put a break point in the `onCreateView` method and verify yourself the `TextView` cannot be found. If you don't know how remove `yearInfo.setText(data);` temporarily from the `setInfo` method. Replace it with a call to `Log.d("My Tag", "I made it here")` so you can see this fixes the problem in your original question. Set some static text using `android:text` on the `TextView` in the layout file so you can see if this view is shown once the `Fragment` appears onscreen.

Comment: I finally found the issue you are likely facing by taking a closer look at the stack trace. Since you are using a `ViewPager` the parent fragment is not yet added to the layout so when you add the child fragment its `onCreateView` method has not been called yet. Because of this it would be best  to move to using arguments as I mentioned in the answer to first display the text. However, move the code you currently have in `onActivityCreated` into the `onResume` method temporarily and it will work.